# Which offline database is suited for a lightweight Chrome App?

Tags: database, google-chrome

I'm starting to learn how to build an app in google chrome.

I want to my app to be operated offline only and its database is offline, this is because I will just use my app inside our office...

Is there a database is very simple way to connect to a database (eg: like I'll just copy paste it in my app folder)? I would prefer that the database has a very simple documentation on how to use it..

your recommendations would be of great help.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: i suggest you check get started tutorial here: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Local storage and similar technology to save the database offline, but it would be different on different machines.